# Backing up full resolution photos from iPhone while using 'Optimize iPhone Storage' with iCloud Photo Library

Tags: icloud, backup, photos.app

I want to help a friend get setup with iCloud Photo Library. They have an iOS device without a lot of free space and they have a PC and an old Mac that can't run Photos.app. In addition to using iCloud Photo Library they want to back up their original photos from their iPhone to their PC or old Mac. I don't think this would be an issue except they don't have enough space to store all of their originals on their iOS device so they must use the 'Optimize iPhone Storage' setting. My fear is that they will only be backing up thumbnails when they go to backup their photos to their desktop. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: They can download the iCloud for Windows and download the pictures to there.

Comment: I don't see anything on about 'iCloud Photo Library' on the iCloud for Windows Apple support article. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204301

Comment: Once you log in to your account on iCloud.com, you will see all of the photos in the iCloud Photo Library, and you can download them from there.

Answer (score 1):

They may have updated the [iCloud Photo Library for Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204301) capabilities:

> ### What you can do with iCloud for Windows
>
> Safely store your photos and videos in iCloud. With iCloud Photo Library, any new photos and videos that you take on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch automatically download to your PC. And you can upload new photos and videos from your PC so that you can access them from your other devices too.